# Modifying and Building Spark core

Tags: scala, sbt, apache-spark, rdd

I am trying to make a modification to the Apache Spark source code. I created a new method and added it to the RDD.scala file within the Spark source code I downloaded. After making the modification to RDD.scala, I built Spark using

```
mvn -Dhadoop.version=2.2.0 -DskipTests clean package
```

I then created a sample Scala Spark Application as mentioned [here](http://people.apache.org/~tdas/spark-1.2-temp/quick-start.html)
I tried using the new function I created, and I got a compilation error when using sbt to create a jar for Spark. How exactly do I compile Spark with my modification and attach the modified jar to my project? The file I modified is RDD.scala within the core project. I run sbt package from the root dir of my Spark Application Project.

Here is the sbt file:

```
name := "N Spark"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.6"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "1.3.0"
```

Here is the error:

```
sbt package
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/Raggy/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Set current project to Noah Spark (in build file:/Users/r/Downloads/spark-proj/n-spark/)
[info] Updating {file:/Users/r/Downloads/spark-proj/n-spark/}n-spark...
[info] Resolving jline#jline;2.12.1 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /Users/r/Downloads/spark-proj/n-spark/target/scala-2.11/classes...
[error] /Users/r/Downloads/spark-proj/n-spark/src/main/scala/SimpleApp.scala:11: value reducePrime is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Int]
[error]     logData.reducePrime(_+_);
[error]             ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 24 s, completed Apr 11, 2015 2:24:03 AM
```

**UPDATE**
Here is the updated sbt file

```
name := "N Spark"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "1.3.0"
```

I get the following error for this file:

```
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/Raggy/.sbt/0.13/plugins
/Users/Raggy/Downloads/spark-proj/noah-spark/simple.sbt:7: error: No implicit for Append.Value[Seq[sbt.ModuleID], sbt.impl.GroupArtifactID] found,
  so sbt.impl.GroupArtifactID cannot be appended to Seq[sbt.ModuleID]
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "1.3.0"
```

Comment: Presumably you made an incorrect change. But since for some odd reason you only give us details of the build output and not the change you made, it's pretty much impossible for us to guess what the error is. However, two possibilities are: your method is called something else, or takes different arguments, or you're not using the Spark you built, but the default.

Comment: How do I check if the Spark being used is the one I built? I used the mvn command to build Spark(I got the Build Success message), but when I use sbt package within my project dir, I am not sure if the dependencies being included are from the Spark I built.

Comment: You need to change your sbt definitions - or how does it know you've got your own copy?

Comment: Yes, that was my assumption too. I mention the dependencies in my sbt file, but I never mention where the root directory of my spark project is.However, I'm not sure how to specify this.

Comment: You have read the doc, right? You need to specify the dependency on your new version of Spark, and not the one in the Maven repository. Start here? http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Library-Dependencies.html

Answer (score 0):

Delete `libraryDependencies` from `build.sbt` and just copy the custom-built Spark jar to the `lib` directory in your application project.

Comment: I changed it to libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "1.3.0" and changed scala version to 2.10(thats the version spark was built with). I get the following error: error: No implicit for Append.Value[Seq[sbt.ModuleID], sbt.impl.GroupArtifactID] found,
  so sbt.impl.GroupArtifactID cannot be appended to Seq[sbt.ModuleID]
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "1.3.0"

Comment: I'm not sure what other jars I need to add to the lib folder. So, I just removed the spark-core dependency and added the spark core jar to the lib folder. But, that creates the above error

Comment: It sounds like you have a syntax error in `build.sbt`.

Comment: I've updated my question to show the modified build.sbt file and the error. I'm not exactly sure why I get this error cause all I did was remove the spark-core dependency.

Comment: Your change is syntactically incorrect. You need `"project" % "artifact" % "version"` in `libraryDependencies`, neither of which are optional. Which part of "delete `libraryDependencies`" did you find confusing in my answer? :) Just delete the whole line. You want to use your custom-built Spark, so just put it in `lib` and don't mention it in `build.sbt`. Delete every mention of Spark from `build.sbt`.